# Format String remove or substring from Serial port without exception, how?

Tags: c#

I'm using this piece of code to receive the weight from scale.

To the part with `.ToString` all is good, but when I call `.Remove(9, 5)` it throws me an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Why? I'm not out of range.

```
private delegate void Closure();

private void sport_DataReceived2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
        BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { sport_DataReceived2(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
    else
    {
        while (sport.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
        {
            textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", sport.ReadExisting().ToString().Remove(9, 5));
            //<-- bytewise adds inbuffer to textbox
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with a substring but still got an exception.

The whole received string is: `"\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r"`

Because of this, I have to use remove or substring, to get what i need exactly - `"00.394KG"` part only.

Comment: I would actually remove all whitespace using `sport.ReadExisting().ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);` and then the operations you need. (obviously handle the single scenarios too) or use regex to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are newline and carriage return characters then you can use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result = "\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r".Split()[1];
```

That will create an array of size 5 where the second item is the one you want, thus the `[1]`.  This will make sure you don't have to worry about the length of the value.  Additionally you should add a check to make sure the array has at least two values if you ever get input that doesn't have at least 1 whitespace character in it.

However if your string truly is "\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r" then `.Remove(9,5)` would not throw the exception you have indicated.  Instead you should get "\n00.394KG\r".  So, I'm guessing you actually have a shorter string and thus the need to split.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking using `Remove`/`Substring` or any other size dependant method on a string which is read during runtime is a bad idea, as you usually don't control the behaviour of your string source, and if that string differs only slightly from what you expect at compile time you get in trouble.

Your code is a perfect example, if you  do a test like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r".Remove(9, 5));
```

Then you can see that your call of remove is not the problem, but the string you are trying to work on differs from what you expected. Probably it is a shorter string as this would produce a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

A safe bet is using regular expressions on any received string and only continue working if the string matches your expectations coded into the regular expression.

```
var recvString = sport.ReadExisting().ToString();
Regex readKGRx = new Regex(@"\n(\d{2}\.\d{3}KG)\r\nS00\r");
var readKGMatch = readKGRx.Match(recvString);
if (readKGMatch.Success) 
    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2}", readKGMatch.Groups[1].Value);
else 
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Bad string received: {0}", recvString));
```

If you don't know how to use regular expressions you should at least store your receive string as a variable and make some checks on it before cutting out what you expect to be there.

```
string expectedFormat = "\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r";
var recvString = sport.ReadExisting().ToString();
bool formatCheckOK = true;
formatCheckOK = formatCheckOK && recvString.Length == expectedFormat.Length;
formatCheckOK = formatCheckOK && recvString[0] == expectedFormat[0];
formatCheckOK = formatCheckOK && recvString.IndexOf("KG") == expectedFormat.IndexOf("KG");
//more checks to be sure...
if (formatCheckOK) 
    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2}", recvString.Substring(1,8));
else 
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Bad string received: {0}", recvString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sport.ReadExisting().ToString().Substring(2, 8)
```

It starts at the 3rd position and goes for 8 characters, so it should return the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think here it not a best chioce in using .remove

sport.ReadExisting().ToString().SubString(9, 5)

Try this instead

Answer (score 0):

Go for a regex solution..

```
var x = "\n00.394KG\r\nS00\r";
var match = Regex.Match(@"(?<serial>\d+\.\d+\w+)", x);
if (!match.Success) throw new FormatException(); // invalid format..
var serial = match.Groups["serial"].Value;
```